# PHP Curl Errors with libidn2-0:amd64 (2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)

Tags: apt, updates, apache2, php

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the repository `ppa:ondrej/php`.

I initially started getting errors in Apache with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in...
```

After Ondřej has released a fix...

- https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1247
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507?comments=all

... when I `apt-get update` or `apt update && apt upgrade` I am still getting the usual

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http:relocation error.
```

Can someone please tell me step by step in simple terms what to do?
Should I follow the procedure in #4 & #12? or is there something else that must be done now that 2.2.0-2 is uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer verified to be working:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507/comments/15

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
dpkg --purge --force-all libidn2-0 && dpkg --purge --force-all libidn2-0 && dpkg --purge --force-all libidn2-0 && dpkg --purge --force-all libidn2-0
dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
apt-mark hold libidn2-0
apt --fix-broken install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```